# Figure out jQuery selector for an image in a link in a span in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, selector, image

I've been having trouble hashing out a selector for the image inside this mess of code below. Originally thought `$('img.gallery')[0];` would work, but it doesn't.. also tried `$('img.advance-link')` and `$('.gallery').find(img)[0];`

Thanks for your help!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UfGrM/

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery front">
    <span class="image-wrapper current">
        <a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#1" title="Title #10">
            <img alt="Title #10" src="../img/10.jpeg">
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with that construct there are many possibilities to access the image:

which range from quick and easy

```
$('.advance-link>img')
```

to rather complex but very specific (only for illustration :) )

```
$('div.gallery.front>span.image-wrapper.current>a.advance-link>img')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Doesn't work in the JS Fiddle environment. http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UfGrM/9/

Comment: Yes it does! You need to choose a jQuery version in the left hand panel

Comment: A much easier method is `$("img:eq(0)").addClass("test");`

Comment: This is a awful advice. It will just change the first image on the entire page. This will almost never work in real life.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.gallery .image-wrapper .advance-link img').css('border', '10px solid black');
```

Just use it like a CSS Selector.

This reads like *search for every image contained by a advance-link wich in turn must be contained by a image-wrapper wich must be inside a gallery*.

When you want access the jQuery result, please consider:

- result[0] will give you the DOM node and no jQuery object, so result[0].attr('href') will be an error
- result.eq(0) will give you a jQuery Object just containing the first result, so result.eq(0).attr('href') will work.

Comment: Thoughtful, thank you. I misunderstood [0] as returning the first element in a string. Anyway, your suggestion doesn't work in the JS Fiddle environment: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UfGrM/10/

Comment: Have you changed the Library setting to jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gallery img').addClass('test');
```

Comment: change the plugin from mootools to jquery

Answer (score 0):

`$("div.gallery img")` should work

Answer (score 0):

`$('img.gallery')` your image doesnt have the class `gallery` one of its parents does.
`$('img.advance-link')` your image doesnt have the class `advance-link` its parent does.

You would need `$('.gallery img')` or `$('.advance-link img')`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Weird I didn't catch that. Even so, it doesn't work for me: jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UfGrM/10

Answer (score 0):

`$("img:eq(0)").addClass("test");`